# Finding $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ for $e^z=xyz$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

This is simply finding $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$.

The question is $$e^z=xyz$$ and what I did was 
$$\ln (e^z)=\ln(xyz)$$ $$z=\ln(xyz)$$ $$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{xyz}\cdot yz = \frac{1}{x}$$

But the answer is $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \dfrac{yz}{e^z-xy}$.

How is this answer gotten?

Comment: here $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\dfrac{1}{xyz}\cdot yz = \dfrac{1}{x}$ the variable $z$ has a derivation.

Comment: You are assuming $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} xyz = yz$, but $z$ is a function of $x$! — Is $y$ a function of $x$ too? The problem is stated very vaguely.

Comment: No I dont think y is a function of x.

Comment: Thanks. It is now clearer

Answer (score 2):

We have $\exp(z)=xyz$ so by assuming $z$ as a function of-for example- $x$ so $$z_x\exp(z)=(xyz)_x=yz+xyz_x
$$

Answer (score 2):

Using your approach. $$\begin{align}z &=\ln (xyz)\\&= \ln x +\ln y+\ln z\\\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} &= \dfrac 1x+\require{cancel}\cancelto0{\dfrac 1y\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}}+\dfrac 1z\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\\(1-\dfrac 1z)\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}&= \dfrac 1x\\ \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} &= \dfrac{z}{x(z-1)}\\ &=\dfrac{yz}{xyz-xy}\\ &= \dfrac{yz}{e^z-xy} \end{align}$$

Note: This assumes $y$ is independent from $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit+

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\dfrac{e^z}{z}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}xy$$
$$\dfrac{z\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}e^z-e^z\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}z}{z^2}=y$$
$$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\dfrac{yz^2}{e^z(z-1)}=\dfrac{z}{x(z-1)}=\dfrac{yz}{xyz-xy}=\dfrac{yz}{e^z-xy}$$

Comment: I cannot find an error in my solution too. Where is wrong?

Comment: Could you find the problem ?

Comment: @Nosrati: nice to see you. +